# Firefox always restores windows and tabs after reboot

Tags: firefox

I have "restore previous session" unchecked and set browser.sessionstore.resume_from_crash to false.

With these settings, I expect it to never reopen the last session.

However, if I do the following, it always does.

1. Open firefox session and open some tabs and windows
2. Reboot using the KDE start menu options
3. Open firefox and it reopens the tabs and windows from last time despite the above settings.

How do I disable this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Normally Firefox will Restore the Session even if you don't have that option selected if it crashes.
Try to open Firefox and select Quit from the menu.

Is possible that you have a plugin that is making crash Firefox on exit.

So before Rebooting KDE, make sure to Quit from Firefox. It should start clean the next time.

Update: Add the link to all the situations where Firefox reopen the open Tabs: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/restore-previous-session

Comment: So even though I have disabled resume from crash, you're telling me it will still resume from a crash?

Comment: Here it explains all the situations where Firefox will restore your tabs, even without asking: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/restore-previous-session

Comment: This is enough to make me go back to Chrome. Web pages can decide not to allow closing without interacting with a prompt, and in these cases I will kill all Firefox processes to start fresh. Not re-opening dozens or hundreds of tabs and sending fresh web requests to each needs to be a working option.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [answer from Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/1iwxus/stop_firefox_from_restoring_previous_session_when/) (formatting my own):

> Type `about:config` in the address bar. Look for the options
>
> ```
> browser.sessionstore.max_tabs_undo
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> browser.sessionstore.max_windows_undo
> ```
>
> Set these both to `0`.
>
> Toggle the setting
>
> ```
> browser.sessionstore.resume_from_crash
> ```
>
> from
> `true` to `false`.
>
> This should completely disable session restore. Information about
> these settings can be found on [Mozillazine](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.sessionstore.max_tabs_undo).

Comment: So I can't disable session restoration without also disabling undoing of tab closing?

Answer (score 0):

To complete BronzeMike answer:

To prevent Firefox from restoring previous session after a shutdown while Firefox was running (i.e. without having manually closed it),
this setting is enough:

Type `about:config` in the address bar.
Toggle from `true` to `false`:

```
browser.sessionstore.resume_from_crash
```

No need to do:

```
Type `about:config` in the address bar. Look for the options
    browser.sessionstore.max_tabs_undo
and
    browser.sessionstore.max_windows_undo
set these both to 0.
```

As these alone do not prevent firefox from restoring previous session after a reboot.